# Using My SQL joins

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am having trouble finishing my MySQL JOIN. I am unsure of the syntax for the last part of my query.

My Query:

```
$posts_query= "
SELECT *
FROM posts p
JOIN relations r ON p.user_id = r.recipient
WHERE (r.status = 1 OR r.status = 2)
AND (r.sender = '".$user_id."' OR p.user_id = '".$user_id."')


// How do I write this part?
AND skip where r.status = 1 and p.privacy = 2 where p.user_id != $user_id // 

ORDER BY p.post_id DESC;
";
```

Comment: What is this query supposed to do?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: You should be very careful when composing queries like this and always use [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to avoid severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). It's not clear if `$user_id` is escaped at all here, which could be extremely bad. If you were using placeholder values you wouldn't have to fuss with things like proper quotation.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of 'skip', just set it so that the value isn't true, using NOT:

```
SELECT *
FROM posts p
JOIN relations r ON p.user_id = r.recipient
WHERE (r.status = 1 OR r.status = 2)
AND (r.sender = '$user_id' OR p.user_id = '$user_id')
AND NOT (r.status = 1 AND p.privacy = 2 AND p.user_id != '$user_id')
ORDER BY p.post_id DESC;"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM posts p
JOIN relations r ON p.user_id = r.recipient
WHERE r.status in (1,2)
AND (r.sender = '$user_id' OR p.user_id = '$user_id')
AND NOT ( r.status = 1 and p.privacy = 2 AND p.user_id != '$user_id' )
ORDER BY p.post_id DESC;
```