# Using two combined MySQL queries

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have a query that I am using to join two tables (posts, relations) to return posts from users you are following (r.status= 1) or friends (r.status= 2) with. But then also omitting the posts where the post privacy is private (p.privacy= 2) and the current relationship (r.status= 1).

Here is my query:

```
$user_id= 1;

$posts_query= "
SELECT DISTINCT post_id, user_id, story, photo, link, collection_id, privacy, date, type
FROM posts p
JOIN relations r ON p.user_id = r.recipient
AND (r.sender = '".$user_id."')
AND NOT (r.status = 1 AND p.privacy = 2)  
ORDER BY p.post_id DESC;
";
```

Now the only problem with this query is that It omits your own personal posts.

The query for that would be:

```
$your_posts_query= "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE user_id= '".$user_id."' ORDER BY p.post_id    
DESC";
```

Now, This doesn't allow me aggregate all of the posts together. Yours, and the ones from your friends and the people you are following.

How can I make it so that my first query also incorporates what my second query does?

Comment: AND (r.sender = '".$user_id."' OR p.user_id= '".$user_id."')

Comment: That won't work because of AND NOT (r.status = 1 AND p.privacy = 2)

Comment: can u post the table structure and some data in sqlfiddle so that its more visible before attempting anything ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21632056/using-my-sql-joins

Comment: @Mr.Radical Radical, your point?

Comment: Is this a continuation of your question you placed 4 hours ago? If so it will help others understand your question better.

Answer (score 0):

```
$user_id= 1;

$posts_query= "
SELECT DISTINCT post_id, user_id, story, photo, link, collection_id, privacy, date, type
FROM posts p
JOIN relations r ON p.user_id = r.recipient
AND (r.sender = '".$user_id."' OR p.user_id= '".$user_id."')
AND NOT (r.status = 1 AND p.privacy = 2)  
ORDER BY p.post_id DESC;
";
```

Answer (score 0):

Combine the two together to get as one result set

```
$posts_query= "
SELECT post_id, user_id, story, photo, link, collection_id, privacy, date, type  
FROM posts WHERE user_id= '".$user_id."' 
union 
SELECT DISTINCT post_id, user_id, story, photo, link, collection_id, privacy, date, type
FROM posts p
JOIN relations r ON p.user_id = r.recipient
AND (r.sender = '".$user_id."')
AND NOT (r.status = 1 AND p.privacy = 2)  
ORDER BY p.post_id DESC;
";
```